# datatables - pagination doesn't work with dynamic data coming from a json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

Since a couple of days i'm encountering a strange problem trying to use the DataTables pagination that is driving me crazy.

The odd thing is that, if i paste, via Firebug, the data printed on my page on the "DataTables Live", i can paginate, but this is not possibile on the page, so clearly there is a problem with my Ajax call.

You can see what's printed here:

http://live.datatables.net/zoxuhewa/1/edit

Here, if you remove the "odd" row, the results are paginated, but, as you can see from the results, this doesn't happen in my webpage.

Let me show you what i do in a Pastebin (i hope they're allowed here):

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="row">
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Cognome</th>
                                <th>Indirizzo</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Tipo contatto</th>
                                <th>Telefono 1</th>
                                <th>Telefono 2</th>
                                <th>Telefono 3</th>
                                <th>Azioni</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tab-0">

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
```

And this is how the JSON data in composed in PHP

```
    if ($result = $this->hookUp->query($this->sqlA)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

            $id = $row['id'];

            $data[] = array("id" => "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>",
                "nome" => "<td id='nome:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>",
                "cognome" => "<td id='cognome:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['cognome'] . "</td>",
                "indirizzo" => "<td id='indirizzo:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['indirizzo'] . "</td>",
                "email" => "<td id='email:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>",
                "tipo_contatto" => "<td id='tipo_contatto:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['tipo_contatto'] . "</td>",
                "telefono_1" => "<td id='telefono_1:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['telefono_1'] . "</td>",
                "telefono_2" => "<td id='telefono_2:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['telefono_2'] . "</td>",
                "telefono_3" => "<td id='telefono_3:" . $id . "' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['telefono_3'] . "</td>",
                "edit" => "<td>" . '<a id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i></a>
                <a id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="edit" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>' . "</a></td>");

            $response['cliente'] = $data;

            $fp = fopen("../lista.json", "w");
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
```

This is how the JSON data is appended:

```
    $.getJSON("lista.json", function (json) {

        if (json.cliente) {

            for (i = 0; i < json.cliente.length; i++) {
                var obj = json.cliente[i];

                var output = "<tr class='row'>";

                for (var key in obj) {
                    name = key;
                    value = obj[key].toString();

                    output += value;
                }

                output += "</tr>";

                console.log(output);

                $("#tab-0").append(output);
            }

        }

 [...] close brackets.
```

The HTML of course is put inside a more wide portion of code (the whole page).

Let me know what i can do, i'm literally going crazy. Thanks.

Comment: Check link now. now its working http://live.datatables.net/zoxuhewa/1/edit

Comment: There is issue with your appending tr inside the tbody.
The First tr is not accurately appending please see this again.

Comment: Umesh, what's wrong with the first <tr>? Could you explain me better?

Comment: Yes,  your first tr showing in live example as

<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="10" clas<tr class="row"><td>509</td><td contenteditable="true" id="nome:509">fgdfgfd</td>

check in the first td's class attribute of tr , you will show syntactically issue.

Comment: Maybe i've posted this incorrectly but i don't find the error http://live.datatables.net/zoxuhewa/1/edit see here. The problem resists.